# Auto connecting to remote machine

Tags: ssh, putty, kitty

I use Kitty (which is pretty much the same as Putty) and when connecting to machines (for example a server through SSH) is there a way to have it remember my login credentials? I notice it has the option to save, but only has options to specify connection type, host name and port. So can it save the host name and password so I don't have to look it up each time I want to login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work flow is like this:

1. put in connection type, host name and port
2. go to data and put in `auto-login username`
3. put in `auto-login password` in data tab, or select a private key in SSH->Auth tab
4. go back to Session tab, put in a name in `saved sessions/new folder`, hit `Saved(d)`
5. next time, just double click on the saved profile.

I myself find the work flow pretty weird and not the most intuitive, as you need to go to many different tabs and you'll need to go back to `Session` tab in the end and hit `Save(d)` to save your edits.

[image]